# Load value dynamically in edit component properties window

Tags: experience-editor, content-editor, templates, components, rendering-parameters

I have a checkbox field(includelevel2) and I need to load the value dynamically in a droptree field(parent folder) based on the checkbox event. Is it possible to achieve because both the fields are located in edit component properties window and added as fields in rendering parameter template. please see the image below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible really.

Sitecore does not support any events on changes of field values that would result in applying some logic in other fields.

That would be heavy change to Sitecore internal javascripts - that's not recommended.